# Prevent browser's loading icon from showing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm making a simple chat app using ZeroMQ for the server. On the client side it's just a "forever frame" of sorts, an infinite loop waiting for messages from the chat server, and a small form to send messages to the server.

It all works fine, but I have one aesthetic problem. As a result (presumably) of the infinite loop, the browser window/tab constantly shows a loading indicator while the page is open. Obviously chat services all over the internet work without the browser showing a loading indicator the whole time. So, how do I get rid of it?

Here is the relevant code. I think the most important bits are the jQuery onLoad function and the part in chat.php that creates a JS call within that infinite loop.

HTML:

```
<div id="chat">
                <div id="chatwindow">
                </div>
                <form id="chatform">
                <input id="chatbox" name="chatbox" type="textarea" value="" />
                        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
            </form>
        </div>
<iframe id="datasrc" src="chat.php?name=myname"></iframe>
```

JS:

```
function updateChat(response) {    //adds newly received message to chat window
                        $('#chatwindow').append('<p>' + response + '</p>');
                }

$(document).ready(function(){
                        $('#chatform').submit(function(e) {    //sends message to chat server through AJAX
                                $.post('send.php', {'name': myname, 'message': $('#chatbox').val()});
                                e.stopPropagation();
                                e.preventDefault();
                                $('#chatbox').val('');
                        });
                });
```

send.php:

```
<?php
//sends message to server, not really important here
```

chat.php:

```
<?php

$context = new ZMQContext();
$sub = new ZMQSocket($context, ZMQ::SOCKET_SUB);
$sub->setSockOpt(ZMQ::SOCKOPT_SUBSCRIBE, '');
$sub->connect('tcp://localhost:5566');
$poll = new ZMQPoll();
$poll->add($sub, ZMQ::POLL_IN);
$readable = $writeable = array();
// Hack for chrome etc. to start polling
echo str_repeat("<span></span>", 100);
ob_flush();
flush();
while(true) {
    $events = $poll->poll($readable, $writeable, 5000000);
    if($events > 0) {    //here is where we call a JS function to update the chat window
        echo "\n\n<script type='text/javascript'>parent.updateChat('" . str_replace("'", "\'", $sub->recv()) ."');</script>\n\n";
    } else {
        echo ".";
    }
    ob_flush();
    flush();
}
```

Comment: Most chat services use ajax or websockets, not a "forever frame". While the frame is loading, there would be no way to stop the browser from showing as loading.

Comment: But isn't this similar to what Comet or long polling does? Can you suggest a modification to make this work without a forever frame, but without installing a webSockets server like Ratchet?